# Derivative and constant function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

### Problem

Suppose that $f:(a,b)\to\Bbb R$ is differentiable and $f^\prime(x)=0$ on $D$, where $D$ is dense on $(a,b)$. Can we conclude that $f$ is a constant function?

### Background

In calculus course, I'm told that there's a theorem stated when $D=(a,b)$. In fact, it's reducible. For example, if $D=(a,b)\backslash C$ where $C$ is at most countable, we have $f^\prime(x)=0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$, because if $k_0=f^\prime(x_0)\neq0$ for some $x_0\in C$, there's some $\xi\in C$ such that $f^\prime(\xi)=\eta$ for all $0\le\eta\le k_0$, so $C$ is uncountable.

Comment: If you can show that $\,f(x)\,$ is a constant on $\,D\,$ then $\,f\,$ for sure is a constant in $\,(a,b)\,$...but can you?

Comment: Without the requirement that $f'$ exists for all $x\in (a,b)$, the [Devil's staircase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devils_staircase) would be a nice counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an everywhere differentiable non-constant function such that the set $Z=\{x: f'(x) = 0 \}$ is dense. The following paper gives an example of such a function:

Y. Katznelson and Karl Stromberg. *Everywhere Differentiable, Nowhere Monotone, Functions.* The American Mathematical Monthly , vol. 81, no. 4 (Apr., 1974), pp. 349-354.

According to this paper:

> Examples of such functions are seldom given, or even mentioned, in books on real analysis. The first explicit construction of such a function was given by Kopcke (1889). An example due to Pereno (1897) is reproduced in [1], pp. 412-421.
>
> ...
>
> [1] E. W. Hobson, Theory of Functions of a Real Variable II, Dover, New York, 1957

Comment: Thanks. What about more stronger? For instance, if $C$ could be covered by a collection (at most countable) of open intervals $\{O_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ whose total length is arbitrary small?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't (but I don't have the example).

Look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112067/how-discontinuous-can-a-derivative-be), where it is stated that the set of discontinuities of a derivative can be dense and have several other properties.