# Does Intermediate Value Theorem $\rightarrow $ continuous?

Tags: calculus, continuity

i try to understand Intermediate Value Theorem and wonder if the theorem works for the opposite side. I mean, if we know that $\forall c\:\:\:f\left(a\right)\le \:c\le \:f\left(b\right)\:,\:\exists x_0\in \left[a,b\right]\:\:$ such that $f\left(x_0\right)=c$ then $f\:$ is continuous in $\left[a,b\right]$? tnx!

**EDITED**: [Continuity $\Rightarrow$ Intermediate Value Property. Why is the opposite not true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622076/continuity-rightarrow-intermediate-value-property-why-is-the-opposite-not-tr?lq=1) there is absolute fantastic answer for this!

Comment: No. For instance, take $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$, $x\ne 0$; $f(0)=0$.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/622076/continuity-rightarrow-intermediate-value-property-why-is-the-opposite-not-tr) for more information.

Answer (score 7):

No. A famous example is the [Conway base-13 function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_base_13_function) which takes every real value on every (positive length) interval.

Answer (score 3):

By [Darboux' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29), every derivative has the intermediate value property. However, not every derivative is a continuous function. Consider, for instance, the Weierstrass function
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(n^2 x)}{n} $$
over $(0,1)$. It is the derivative of a differentiable function, hence it has the intermediate value property, but it is not a continuous function. Another interesting fact is that every real function can be written as the sum of two functions with the IVP (see *Andrew M. Bruckner, Differentiation of real functions*), so the space of functions with the IVP is not even a vector space. See also [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327243/is-every-function-with-the-intermediate-value-property-a-derivative).

Comment: I heard that Darboux' theorem help in this, would you mind elaborating on that matter?

Answer (score 0):

No, what about $f(x)=x$ if $0\le x<1$ and $f(1)=1/2$. Clearly this has the property you stated with $a=0,b=1$ but is not continuous in $[0,1]$.