# Under what conditions can a function $ y: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ be expressed as $ z z' $?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

This is a follow-up to [Under what conditions can a function $ y: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ be expressed as $ \dfrac{z'}{z} $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835145/under-what-conditions-can-a-one-variable-real-function-y-be-written-as-df). It turns out that in that case,
\begin{align}
       \text{$ y = \dfrac{z'}{z} $ for some differentiable $ z $}
& \iff \text{$ y $ has an anti-derivative} \\
& \iff \text{$ y $ is discontinuous on a meager $ F_{\sigma} $-subset of $ \mathbb{R} $}.
\end{align}
I was thus wondering whether the answer is still the same in this case.

Comment: And your take on this would be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Claim:** Let $ y: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $. Then there exists a differentiable $ z: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ such that $ y = z z' $ if and only if $ y $ has a non-negative anti-derivative.

*Proof*: Suppose that there exists a differentiable $ z: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ such that $ y = z z' $. Then
$$
y = z z' = \left( \frac{1}{2} z^{2} \right)'.
$$
Hence, $ \dfrac{1}{2} z^{2} $ is a non-negative anti-derivative of $ y $.

Conversely, suppose that $ y $ has a non-negative anti-derivative. By adding the constant function $ 1 $ to it, we obtain a *positive* anti-derivative $ F $ of $ y $. Let $ z \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \sqrt{2 F} $. Then $ z $ is well-defined (since $ F \geq 0 $), is positive and is differentiable everywhere (since $ F > 0 $). By the Chain Rule,
$$
  z'
= (\sqrt{2 F})'
= \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2 F}} \cdot 2 F'
= \frac{F'}{\sqrt{2 F}}
= \frac{y}{z}.
$$
Hence, $ y = z z' $. $ \quad \blacksquare $