# Making a piecewise function continuous and differentiable at point

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

**Problem:**

Let $f(x) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    \frac{\arctan(x)}{(1+x)^2} & : x \geq 0\\
    Ae^x + B & : x < 0
  \end{array}
\right.
$

Find $A$ and $B$ such that the function is continuous and differentiable at $x=0$.

**My attempt:**

To ensure continuity at $x = 0$ I figured $A = B = 0$ would be the only option. But this, of course, seems very wrong, and in any case, it wouldn't cause differentiability at $x=0$.

As far as I could tell, the derivative of $\frac{\arctan(x)}{(1+x)^2}$ at $x=0$ would be $1$. While the second piece's derivative evaluates trivially to $0$.

Comment: "To ensure continuity at $x = 0$ I figured $A = B = 0$ would be the only option". Once you fix this mistake, you should be able to get the correct answer. What is $\lim \limits_{x\to 0^{\mathbf -}}(f(x))$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is *continuous* at $0$ means that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)&=\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)
\\\iff0&=A+B.
\end{align*}
Also, $f$ is *differentiable* at $0$ means that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to0^+}f'(x)&=\lim_{x\to0^-}f'(x)
\\\iff1&=A.
\end{align*}
(actually, this is valid since each piecewise defined part is smooth in its given domain.)
Thus we have $A=1,B=-1$.

Comment: @GitGud Oh, my mistake. I edited.

Comment: Also $f$ being differentiable at $0$ doesn't *mean* that $\lim \limits_{x\to0^+}f'(x)=\lim \limits_{x\to0^-}f'(x)$. In fact $\lim \limits_{x\to0^+}f'(x)=\lim \limits_{x\to0^-}f'(x)$ means that $f$ is differentiable and $f'$ is continuous and  [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/423279) is well known not to be necessarily true.

Comment: @GitGud To be precisely, yes. What we actually have to do is using the definition of derivitive and check that whether the limit exists. But I think "thinking in this way" is reasonable since both piecewise defined funtion are smooth in their given domain. We can prove that $\lim_{x\to a^+}g'(x)=\lim_{x\to a^+}(g(x)-g(a))/(x-a)$ if $g$ is smooth and so on.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $f$ is differentiable in 0 iff you have in a neighborhood of 0:

$$
f(x) = a + bx + o(x)
$$

Here when $x>0$ you have
$$
f(x) = x + o(x)
$$so it is mandatory that
$$a=0, b=1
$$

but when $x<0$ you have
$$f(x) = A(1+x + o(x)) + B
$$