# Construction of a function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Give an example of a function that is **partial differentiable** and **differentiable** but not **continuous partial differentiable** .

---

One example I thought (but is wrong) is the function:
$$f(x, y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\dfrac{xy}{x^2+y^2} &,\left ( x, y \right )\in \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\left \{ \left ( 0,0 \right ) \right \} \\ 
0 &, (x, y)=(0, 0) 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Now I don't have any ideas on how to construct any function.
Any ideas?

Comment: Just consider the standard one variable example.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292275/discontinuous-derivative/423279#423279).

Comment: How does this help? I am aware of that example in one-variable calculus?

Comment: That function is partially differentiable, differentiable, but its partial derivative (which coincides with the derivative) is not continuous.