# Differentiable continuous function whose derivative is not continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, examples-counterexamples

Is there a function which is **continuous** and **differentiable**, but **is not smooth** function?

By **smooth** I mean having continuous derivative. For example, the derivative of $f(x)=x|x|/2$ is $f'(x)=|x|$ which is continuous. So I consider this function  smooth.

Comment: Does $x\mapsto |x|$ have an antiderivative?

Comment: I think yes, x|x|/2

Comment: @GitGud Isn't that antiderivative smooth?

Comment: What does it mean for a function to be smooth?

Comment: To have continuous derivatives. The derivative of x|x|/2 is |x| which is continuous. So I think it's smooth

Comment: To follow-up on Git Gud's comment, there are many different uses of "smooth". For instance, one of the theorems in my Ph.D. thesis involves smooth functions (more precisely, functions that are non-smooth at each point), but I bet the notion is different than what you're asking about.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I didn't know about that, I thought *smooth* could only mean infinitely differentiable.

Comment: @user96634 In view of Dave's comment above, please add the definition of *smooth* to the question.

Comment: Also of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292275/discontinuous-derivative

Comment: @Fundamental Thanks

Comment: @Git Gud: Off-hand, I can think of three different notions I've seen "smooth" refer to, and if I were sufficiently inclined to (which I'm not), I suspect I could find one or two more if I dug around for a couple of days. The three notions I can think of are continuously differentiable, infinitely differentiable, and what I call (to avoid ambiguity) "Zygmund smooth", the last of which can be found [here](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077472961) among many other places.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One standard example is $f(0) = 0$, $f(x) = x^2*\sin(1/x)$. Then $f'(0) = 0$, but $f'$ is not continuous at $0$.