# Question about differentiability/continuity,please help

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

I was reading in my textbook that it says "a function $ f $ may have a derivative $ f' $ which exists at every point, but is discontinuous at some point."

Before this there is a theorem that says that if a point is differentiable then it's also continuous. I think I'm missing something; how can this be true?

Comment: the derivative $f'$ may be discontinuous

Comment: but how can this be true, because if $ f' $ exists at a point doesn't that point have to be continuous?

Comment: You are confusing the continuity of $f$ at some point (necessary for $f'$ at this point to exist) with the continuity of $f'$ at the same point.

Comment: yes I understand now, thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theorem says: if $f'$ exists at a point, then $f$ is continuous at that point (but $f'$ may or may not be continuous).

The example says: there is a function $f$ that has a derivative $f'$ and $f'$ is not continuous (but $f$ is).

Comment: but if the $ f $ is continuous doesn't $ f' $ also have to be continuous?

Comment: Is there an example of a differentiable continuous function with a discontinuous derivative?

Comment: @user1961722: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sr9KJh18eBE)

Comment: ok thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Have you already read the following answer? Probably not and I advice you to do so: [discontinuous derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/423279/207868).

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm having a hard time intuitively understanding why this can be true but the example makes sense.