# Is Thomae's function Riemann integrable on every interval?

Tags: real-analysis

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function

It seems to me that on every interval in $\mathbb{R}$, the function is bounded and its set of discontinuities is just the set of rational numbers in that interval, which is countable and therefore of measure zero, so it's Riemann integrable on every interval. But every page on the Internet I've found says that it's Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$ without saying anything about the rest of $\mathbb{R}$. Is my reasoning accurate?

Follow-up question: is it correct then to say that $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \,\mathrm{d}t$ where $f(t)$ denotes Thomae's function is by construction differentiable everywhere?

The motivation behind this is that I'm trying to look for a simple function that is differentiable but has a derivative that is discontinuous at infinitely many points.

Comment: Yes, this function is Riemann integrable on every interval. As for the second question, you can easily see that $F(x)$ is always zero, so $F'(x)$ is zero.

Comment: @Crostul: Hm I see why that's true but why isn't it valid to say that $F'(x) = f(x) - f(0) = f(x)$?

Comment: @Crostul: Never mind I see that the FT of calculus requires continuity.

Comment: Regarding your final paragraph, have you seen the "standard example" of a differentiable function with discontinuous derivative?

Comment: @user86418: I think so; I just read http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292275/discontinuous-derivative/.

Comment: @ElizabethLin: Ah, that probably answers your question. :)