# "alternate definition" of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

I was trying to find a definition of the continuity of a function that fits better the unrirgorous definition that "it can be drawed with a pencil in a single stroke" and I came up with this:
a function $f : I → R$ is "continuous" iff for any $a, b \in I$ and any $\alpha \in (f(a), f(b))$ there is an $x \in (a, b)$ so that $f(x) = \alpha$. 
Basically this means that between two points $a$ and $b$ $f$ must assume all values between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$.

This definition is obviously no equivalent to the normal definitions since functions such as $\frac{1}{x}$ and $\tan x$ would not be continuous. But on the other hand they cannot be drawn in a single stroke (kind of). I myself find it a lot more intuitive than the normal definitions.

What I would want to know is:

- how much sense does this definition make?
- Is it correct for functions whose domain is connected (so not $\frac1x$, $\tan x$)?

English is not my first language and I don't learn math in English, so I may have used some terms wrongly. Please ask if something doesn't make sense.

Comment: it is called the **intermediate value property**. the class of functions satisfying that property is larger than the class of continuous functions.

Comment: Note also that the class of functions that comes closest to "can be drawed with a pencil in a single stroke" is the set of Lipschitz-continuous functions. Functions with less continuity can look very uncontinuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed definition is of functions usually called [Darboux functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)#Darboux_function). For example, every derivative (of a differentiable function) has this property, but there are others as well. For example
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} \sin \frac1x, & x \neq 0 \\ 0, & x = 0. \end{cases}
$$

Comment: The Wikipedia article on Darboux functions states: "A Darboux function is a real-valued function f [...] for any two values a and b in the domain of f, and any y between f(a) and f(b), there is some c between a and b with f(c) = y". This doesn't seem to apply to $f(x) = \frac1x$ with a = -1, b = 1 and y = 0, although the Wikipedia article states, that "[...] every continuous function is a Darboux function". Am i making an error or is there an "on an intervall" missing in the article?

Comment: @0x539 the domain of $1/x$ is not connected, neither is the domain of $\tan$.

Comment: @user251257 yet they are Darboux functions. The Wikipedia articles definition would not make them Darboux functions.

Comment: @0x539 the intermediate value property makes only sense for functions with connected domain or which can be extended in that way. The wiki is sloppy

Comment: @user251257 so any continuous function with a connected domain which satisfies the intermediate value property is a Darboux function. (or do they have to satisfy the intermediate property on a connected subset of their domain?)

Comment: @0x539 continuous function on an interval (these are the only connected subsets of the reals) always has the intermediate value property.

Answer (score 1):

This definition is *not* correct for functions whose domain is connected.

[Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)), also called the "intermediate value theorem for derivatives," states that all derivatives have your property. However, there are [discontinuous derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292275/discontinuous-derivative), some of them wildly so.