# Clarification on differentiable function and functions whose derivatives are continous

Tags: calculus

Is every function whose derivative exists at a point differentiable? And, if a function is differentiable does it mean that the derivative is continous?

Comment: Are you talking about single-variable functions or multi-variable functions?

Comment: Hint: for the first question consider a function that is zero everwhere except on the interval $(0,1)$, where it is has the value one; i.e $\chi_{(0,1)}$. For the second question consider the function that is defined to be $x^2sin(1/x)$ everywhere except $x=0$ and, and 0 at $x=0$.

Comment: @Merlinsbeard this should be an answer.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292275/discontinuous-derivative and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292275/discontinuous-derivative