# Continuity - is it allowed to use the first derivation and then prove continuity on it instead of using the normal function?

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, derivatives

In order to prove continuity of a function, you need to show that
the left side limit and right side limit of the function are identical.
Then you need to show that the function value and (left-right) limit are same... You do this all on the normal function.

Now my question, would it be allowed to use the first derivation of the function instead of the normal function?

Example (using normal function): Prove that $f(x) = x^{2}$ is continuous at $x_{0}=1$.

$\lim_{x\rightarrow1^{-}}x^{2}=1$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow1^{+}}x^{2}=1$

Thus the function is continuous.

---

Example (using first derivative): Prove that $f(x) = x^{2}$ is continuous at $x_{0}=1$.

$f'(x)=2x$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow1^{-}}2x=2$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow1^{+}}2x=2$

Thus the function is continuous.

Comment: You can't... try with a discontinous function like $sgn x$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, it is not.**

First of all, for what you suggest to be possible to begin with, you need your function to be differentiable on a deleted neighborhood of the point. So you'd have to show that $f$ is differentiable on some set $[a-\varepsilon,a-\varepsilon]\setminus\{a\}$. This is not necessarily trivial.

Moreover, it's not even sufficient. 
Consider the function $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ by $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0&\text{ if } x\neq 1\\1&\text{ if } x=1\end{cases}$$
By your method, since $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}$ with derivative identically zero, you would get continuity of $f$ at $1$... that's *slightly* problematic. $f$ is definitely **not** continuous at $1$.

Comment: Ok ty Clemens. So for proving continuity I will use the normal function and take the left right limit as I described in my question right? Check if they are same if same then its continuous.

Comment: And for proving that function is differentiable, I will take first derivation of function and check left right limit, is it correct? Check if same and if it's same function is differentiable.

Comment: There are several ways to prove continuity, but yes -- that's one of the basic (and safe) approaches. Compute two one-sided limits, show they are equal *and* equal to the value of the function at the point (I think you are missing that).

Comment: For differentiability, there are also several methods, but using the definition as liit of $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ is safe -- what you suggest above will not work in general. You can have $f$ not differentiable at a point but such that $f'$ exists everywhere else and has a limit at that point.

Comment: Ok say I need show $f(x)=x^{2}$ is differentiable at $x_{0}=1$. I can't do this? $\lim_{x\rightarrow1^{-}}f'(x)=2x=2\cdot1=2$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow1^{+}}f'(x)=2x=2\cdot1=2$? Conclude: Function is differentiable.

Comment: No. Read the above. From the definition, what you *should* do is show that $\frac{(x_0+h)^2-x_0^2}{h}$ has a limit when $h\to 0$. This limit will be the derivative.

Comment: @tenepolis A classic example would be (as in the [first part of this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/423279/75808)) the function $f$ defined by $f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2\sin\frac{1}{x} & x\neq 0\\ 0 & x=0\end{cases}$. $f$ is differentiable at $0$ (and everywhere else has well), but $f'$ has no limit at $0$.

Comment: I don't like use h method... Ok I think I understand, I can use instead h method this: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow1^{-}}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=\lim_{x\rightarrow1^{-}}\frac{x^{2}-1}{x-1}= \lim_{x\rightarrow1^{-}}\frac{(x+1)(x-1)}{(x-1)}= \lim_{x\rightarrow1^{-}}x+1=2$$ then do same for right side... I hope is right now?

Comment: Yes. It is exactly the same as the "$h$-method," by the way... $h=x-1$ here.

Answer (score 1):

Continuity does not imply differentiability. However, if you know that a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at a point $x_0$, then this implies immediately that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

It seems what you're trying to prove is that the derivative of the function is also continuous at $x_0$, which is an even stronger condition than continuity of the function at that point.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got you right. But my aim is, when there is a function given and I'm supposed to say if it's continuous at a specific place, but I cannot really say that because it won't work if I insert $x_{0}$ in the function (let's say because we got a zero in the denominator). Would I be allowed to use the first derivation and insert $x_{0}$ there for $x$? And then conclude if function is continuous or not...?

Comment: If the function is not defined at the point $x_0$, then it can not be continuous there since the point $x_0$ is not in the domain of the function. It could happen that you have a piecewise defined function, something like: $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} & x \neq 0 \\ 1 & x = 0 \end{cases}$$ but in this case, you can evaluate $f(x)$ at $x_0 = 0$ since $f(0) = 1$ by definition.