# A continuous function, with discontinuous derivative, but the limit must exist.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives

I was reading [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292275/discontinuous-derivative).

The simplest examples of continuous functions, with discontinuous derivatives in some point, are usually of the form:

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 
  x^2 \sin(1/x) &\mbox{if } x \neq 0 \\
0 & \mbox{if } x=0. 
\end{cases}
$$
The derivative of $f$ is 
$$
f'(x) = \begin{cases} 
  2 x \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-\cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)&\mbox{if } x \neq 0 \\
0 & \mbox{if } x=0,
\end{cases}
$$

The derivative is discontinuous because the limit of $\cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ does not exist for $x\rightarrow 0$.

Is there an example where the derivative is still discontinuous but with existing limit?

Thanks

Comment: No. If the limit exists at 0, then this means that the derivative can be continuously extended to 0 making $f$ continuously differentiable at 0. Moreover, one can show that if $f$ is differentiable at 0, but $f'$ is discontinuous at 0, then $f'$ oszillates around 0. This is a consequence of the Intermediate Value Theorem for Derivatives, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)

Comment: @sranthrop thanks for your comment. Would you like to write an answer for the second part of your comment? +1 ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is differentiable in some neighborhood $(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ of $x$, and $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow x}{f'(t)}$ exists. Define $y:(x-\delta,x+\delta)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $y(t)$ is strictly between $x$ and $t$ and
$$f(t)-f(x) = f'(y(t))(t-x)$$
for every $t\in(x-\delta,x+\delta)$. The existence of such a function is guaranteed by the Mean Value Theorem. Since $y(t)$ is between $x$ and $t$ for every $t$, this implies that $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow x}{y(t)} = x$, and **since $y(t)\ne x$ for $t\ne x$ as well**, we have $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow x}{f'(y(t))}=\lim\limits_{s\rightarrow x}{f'(s)}$ by the composition law (think of $s = y(t)$ in this substitution). This implies that
$$f'(x) = \lim\limits_{t\rightarrow x}{\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}} = \lim\limits_{t\rightarrow x}{f'(y(t))} = \lim\limits_{t\rightarrow x}{f'(t)},$$
i.e. $f'$ is continuous at $x$.

---

Remark: Typically, the composition law is phrased as follows: if $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow c}{g(x)} = a$ and **$f$ is continuous at $a$**, then $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow c}{f(g(x))} = \lim\limits_{u\rightarrow a}{f(u)}$. In our problem, we obviously cannot assume $f'$ is continuous at $x$, since that is what we are trying to show. However, the above conclusion still holds if we merely require that $g(x)\ne a$ if $x\ne c$ in some neighborhood of $c$. A proof of this can be found [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Limit_of_Composite_Function) (look for "Hypothesis 2").

Comment: Joey, I have a doubt. I understand how y tends to x, but I cannot understand why f'(y) can have the same limit as f'(t). What are you using there?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. I am using the composition law for limits: basically, $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow x}{f'(y(t))} = \lim\limits_{s\rightarrow\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow x}{y(t)}}{f'(s)}$. However, there is a subtlety that I need to address, and I will edit the answer shortly to address it.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. I have updated the answer. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Yes, it is. I had never heard of that condition, i.e., it's the first time I'm seeing it . Is it common in more advanced subjects?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. If you mean the condition that $g(x)\ne a$ for $x\ne c$ implies the composition law, then I'm not sure. It is related to the distinction between a *limit point* and an *accumulation point* in point-set topology, where a limit point is a limit of a sequence whose terms do not include the point itself, while an accumulation point is the limit of a sequence whose terms can include the point itself. So every limit point is an accumulation point, but not vice versa. The distinction between the two is useful somewhere, although I can't exactly say where right now.