# What is the geometric significance of differentiable vs continuously differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

What is the geometric significance of differentiable vs continuously differentiable for functions (based on $\mathbb{R}$)?  By 'geometric' i mean the appearance of the plot of such functions.

Perhaps this question is best splilt into three categories: $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: See the graphs in Mark McClure's answer to [Discontinuous derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/423279/13130), especially the last graph. Essentially this is the only type of behavior that differentiable functions can have in the vicinity of a point where the derivative is not continuous --- see, as a result of observations [A continuous function, with discontinuous derivative, but the limit must exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1909965/13130) and [Discontinuous derivative *not* by oscillation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1746131/13130).