# Is it possible for a continuous function to have a nowhere-continuous derivative?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, examples-counterexamples

This is motivated by a question I saw elsewhere that asks whether there is a real-valued function on an interval that contains no monotone subintervals.

Edit: Note that I am asking for a function whose derivative *exists* but is not continuous anywhere.

Comment: You should clarify if you're assuming that the function is differentiable...

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292275/discontinuous-derivative/292380#292380) in mathbeing's link. No such function exists, because the set of points where an everywhere-differentiable function is continuous is a $G_{\delta}$ set.

Answer (score 2):

(Adding back someone else's answer that was deleted for some reason.
)

Answer: **NO**: If $f$ is differentiable everywhere on $\mathbb R$, then $f'$ is continuous somewhere.

Suppose $f$ is differentiable everywhere.  Then $f$ is continuous everywhere.  The functions
$$
g_n(x) = \frac{f\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)-f(x)}{\frac{1}{n}}
$$
are continuous and converge pointwise everywhere to $f'(x)$.  Therefore $f'(x)$ is of Baire class $1$, and therefore has lots of points of continuity.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the [Weierstrass Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassFunction.html)

It is continuous everywhere and only differentiable at a set of points with measure 0. I don't know if that suffices for you, but I think it is quite amazing already.

Comment: I thought of that too at first, but I think the question assumes implicitly that the function is differentiable.

Comment: Do you have a reference for your statement of the Weierstrass function? What is the characterization of the set?

Comment: user48672 if you follow the link in the answer, you will see my reference