# Functions whose derivative is not continuous on a dense subset

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Are there differentiable functions $F:(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where the set of points at which the derivative of $F$ is discontinuous, is dense in $(a,b)$?

So far I've only found functions where derivatives are discontinuous only at a finite number of points.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292275/discontinuous-derivative