# Differentiable function $f$ such that one of its partials is not continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, continuity, intuition

Is it possible to have a function $f:G\subseteq \mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$, differentiable in a point $(x,y)\in G$, such that one of its partials is not continuous at $(x,y)$?

I think that it is not possible to find such a function $f$. Because if $f$ is differentiable at some point $(x,y)$, then it is continuous at that point.

Also $f'$ must be equal to ($\partial f_1,\partial f_2$).

Is my argumentation correct?

Comment: You don't even need to several variables [for that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/423279/26489).

Comment: So it is possible and the example would be f(x) = \begin{cases} 
  x^2 \sin(1/x) &\mbox{if } x \neq 0 \\
0 & \mbox{if } x=0. 
\end{cases} ? @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy

Comment: Well at least you have to put $g(x,y)=f(x)$ since required is a function on $\Bbb{R}^2$ :P

Comment: Ok so I just change $f(x)$ by $g(x,y)$ and in both cases  should  I write $y=0$ ? @LiChunMin :)

Comment: @AnneliseToft I think the function is already well defined after you define for the cases $x=0$ and $x\neq 0$?

Comment: Oh ok, so the only change would be g instead of f ? @LiChunMin

Comment: Put it this way then: you shall put $(x,y)$ as the argument of your function.

Comment: like this $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}    x^2 \sin(1/x) &\mbox{if } x \neq 0 \\ 0 & \mbox{if } x=0.  \end{cases}$  ? @LiChunMin

Comment: Yeah. Exactly. $$

Comment: ah finally.. thanks @LiChunMin