# Derivative exists implies derivative continuous

Tags: analysis, derivatives, continuity

It seems to me that if $f^{'}$ exists in an open interval $I$, then $f^{'}$ is continuous in the interval.

I can't come up with an example that $f^{'}$ exists, but $f^{'}$ not continuous.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292275/discontinuous-derivative Of interest ?

Answer (score 5):

The following function:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x} & x \ne 0 \\
0 & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
is differentiable everywhere (the derivative at $0$ is $0$, by the squeeze lemma), but the derivative is (wildly) discontinuous at $0$.

This is a great function to keep in your pocket as you look at conjectures in analysis, because it tends to break things. :)

Your conjecture is *almost* right, in the sense that the derivative of an everywhere-differentiable function is not guaranteed to be continuous, but it *does* have the intermediate value property. That's known as Darboux's theorem. See [this description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) for some details.