# $f$ is differentiable $\Rightarrow$ we can find $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is monotonic on $I$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Is it true that :

$f$ is differentiable $\Leftrightarrow$ we can find $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is monotonic on $I$ where $I = [a, b]$ ($a \ne b$ and $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$).

If this is true I really don't know how to prove such result...
My intuition is saying that this is true because by definition if $f$ is differentiable then the function has a tagent line on every point of $\mathbb{R}$ and hence is monotonic, but I am not sure .

Comment: You probably mean $I\subseteq \mathbf{R}$.

Comment: you have $\in,$ should be $\subset$

Comment: true my bad ! Thank you

Comment: How could $\impliedby$ hold?

Comment: Lol yes should have asked for $\Rightarrow$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't true. Take $f(x)=\lvert x\rvert$. It is monotone decreasing on $(-\infty,0)$ and monotone increasing on $(0,\infty)$, but yet it isn't differentiable at $x=0$.

To remedy this problem, you might ask that this condition apply pointwise. That is, what if we required that $f$ be monotone on a neighborhood of each point. We could make the following conjecture:

> **Conjecture**: $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbf{R}$ if and only if for all $x\in \mathbf{R}$ there exists an open neighborhood $U$ so that $f$ is monotone on $U$.

This also ends up failing. Take $f(x)=x^2$. This is definitely a smooth function, but at $x=0$, we have a turning point, in the sense that $f'(x)<0$ on $(-\infty, 0)$ and $f'(x)>0$ on $(0,\infty)$. So, on no neighborhood of $0$ is $f$ monotone.

Returning to the original problem, we have the following conjecture:

> **Conjecture**: If $f$ is continuously differentiable on $\mathbf{R}$, then there exists an interval $I=[a,b]\subset \mathbf{R}$ so that $f$ is monotone on $I$.

**Proof:** If $f$ is continuously differentiable, then either $f'(x)=0$ on all of $\mathbf{R}$ or not. If $f'(x)=0$ everywhere, then we have that $f$ is constant, so that it is indeed monotone everywhere. If $f'(x)\ne 0$ somewhere (say $f'(x_0)>0$) then by continuity, there must exist some open neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ so that $f'(x)>0$ on $U$. Indeed, then, $f$ is monotone increasing on $U$.

Comment: Thank you, but is $\Rightarrow$ true ?

Comment: @Salutsalut1 No, it is not. See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/167323/everywhere-differentiable-function-that-is-nowhere-monotonic).

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Your conjecture is trivially correct !  I am surprised you provide a proof  to reject it !!!

Comment: Let there exist a point such that $f'(x) > 0$ then ....

Comment: i don't know Weierstrass function, but are you sure it is nowhere monotone, I mean it's hard to see how it can be possible...

Comment: Second conjecture is true: If $f'(x)>0$ somewhere, then $f'>0$ in an interval centered at $x$ which implies $f$ is increasing on this interval. Same if some $f'(x)<0.$ We're left with the case $f'\equiv 0,$ which implies $f$ is constant

Comment: This should be correct now. Sorry lol

Comment: This answer does not address the interesting part of the question asked: If $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R,$ does there exist an interval of positive length on which $f$ is monotone?

Comment: Your last conjecture is a heavily diluted form of the problem being discussed here. You should at least say a word or two about the problem asked.

Comment: @zhw.: the desired implication appears true. Derivatives should be continuous at some point after all. But I am not sure.

Comment: @zhw.: see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/292380/72031