# Is the derivative of a continuous and differentiable density function continuous on its domain?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability-distributions

Suppose a continuous and differentiable density function $f$, defined on $[a,b]$. Is $f'$ continuous on $[a,b]$? What conditions are required to make this statement true?

Comment: 1) Not necessarily. 2) Just tautological ones, basically.

Comment: Derivatives [can be discontinuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292275/discontinuous-derivative)