# Finding an example of a function $f(x)$ that is differentiable on $(a,b)$ but $f'(x)$ is not continuous on $(a,b)$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

I have attempted to come up with functions that are continuous and differentiable on an arbitrary interval $(-1, 1)$, but their derivative is not continuous on $(-1,1)$, ideally due to a division by zero in the denominator. Perhaps it is due to the time, or my ignorance, but I am failing at arriving at an example. This is a recommended practice problem for an upcoming exam, just so I'm transparent.

Comment: I think your textbook might have demonstrated such kind of examples. Make use of those.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292275/discontinuous-derivative

Comment: @xbh, if only that were the case. My textbook is probably the vaguest intro to analysis textbook ever written. Thank you for the reference T. Ford! If you want to link that as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: OK, then. If you haven't seen such things, it would be pretty struggle for you to construct.