# Are all functions that have a primitive differentiable?

Tags: calculus

> Are all functions that have a primitive differentiable?

For some background, I know that not all functions that are integrable are differentiable. For example:

$$
f = 
\begin{cases}
0 & x \neq 0 \\
1 & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$

is integrable over $\mathbb{R}$, and $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = 0$. However, a function $F(x)$ such that $F'(x) = f(x) \space \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ does not exist.

But I can't find a counterexample to the statement: "All functions that have a primitive are differentiable". These functions are guaranteed to be continuous due to the fundamental theorem of calculus, but not every continuous function is differentiable, hence the question.

Thanks !

---

Edit: here is a very important comment from @HenningMakholm that I thought would be useful for other students encountering this question

> Also, (real) functions that have a primitive are not necessarily continuous. For example,
>
> $$
> f(x) = 
> \begin{cases}
> 0 & \text{for } x = 0 \\
> 2x \sin(\frac{1}{x}) - \cos(\frac{1}{x}) & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>
> is discontinuous at $x=0$, but nevertheless the derivative of
>
> $$
> F(x) = 
> \begin{cases}
> 0 & \text{ for } x = 0 \\
> x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x}) & \text{ otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>
> Functions that have a primitive do have [the intermediate-value property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) but that is weaker than being continuous.

Comment: Any continuous function on a closed bounded interval has a primitive, but not all continuous functions are differentiable.

Comment: Take a function that is $C^1$ but not $C^2$.

Comment: @dmtri That is not enough. Your conditions allow for the existence of a discontinuous second derivative.

Comment: @Andres,  you are right! I was focusing more on differentiability

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292275/discontinuous-derivative

Comment: Note that, famously, this **is** true for functions defined on an open subset of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Also, (real) functions that have a primitive are _not_ necessarily continuous. For example, $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{for }x=0 \\ 2x\sin(1/x) - \cos(1/x) & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$ is discontinuous at $x=0$, but is nevertheless the derivative of $$ F(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{for }x=0 \\ x^2\sin(1/x) & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$
Functions that have a primitive [do have the intermetdiate-value property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) but that is weaker than being continuous.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I'm integrating (no pun intended) your comment in the question for future reference. Thanks a lot !

Comment: +1 because you make the question useful for a larger class of people

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A primitive for $f(x)=x^{1/3}$ is $F(x)=\frac{3}{4}x^{4/3}$, but $f'(0)$ doesn't exist, because $$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{x^{1/3}}{x}=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{1}{x^{2/3}}=\infty$$

Comment: Almost. What you wrote is $f'(x)$ for $x\ne0$; you need an additional argument to ensure that $f'(0)$ does not exist.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I edited to be more clarifying

Answer (score 15):

Even more simply: $f(x) := |x|$.

Comment: Of course, how did I not think about that ? I already accepted the @Martin's answer, but thanks for the example ! For further reference, I'll just state here that $\int |x| dx = \frac{1}{2}x|x|$

Answer (score 5):

Any bounded function that has discontinuity at a single point is integrable but of course that function will be non differentiable.

Comment: @Martin has justified my statement.