# Definition of a piecewise smooth path

Tags: complex-analysis

In Apostol's "Mathematical Analysis" $($page 435$)$, a piecewise smooth path in the complex plane, say $f$, is defined as a path in the complex plane that has bounded derivative $f'$ which is continuous everywhere except possibly at a finite number of points, and at these exceptional points it is required that both right- and left-hand derivatives exist. Specifically, if $f:[a,b]\rightarrow C$ is a complex-valued function on the compact interval $[a,b]$,
then $f$ is said to be piecewise smooth if there exists a partition $\{x_0,x_1,...x_n\}$ of $[a,b]$ such that $f$ has a bounded and continuous derivative on each open subinterval $(x_{i-1},x_i)$ and has one-sided derivatives at the endpoints $x_{i-1}$ and $x_i$.

However, in the definition of a piecewise smooth path in most books on complex analysis, it is required that the restriction of $f$ to each compact subinterval $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ has a "continuous" derivative on $[x_{i-1},x_i]$. The requirement in this definition is stronger than that of Apostol since at the endpoints $x_{i-1}$ and $x_i$ it requires that $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{i-1}+}f'(x)=f'_{+}(x_{i-1})$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_i-}f'(x)=f'_{-}(x_i)$. I would like to know whether Apostol's definition is equivalent to this definition. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: You should revise your question instead of adding comments (which are still unclear).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292275/discontinuous-derivative

Answer (score 3):

The two definitions are not equivalent.

For example, take $a = -1,$ $b = 1,$ $(x_0, x_1, x_2) = (-1, 0, 1),$ and:
$$
\gamma \colon [-1, 1] \to \mathbb{C}, \ x \mapsto
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } x = 0, \\
x + ix^2\sin\left(\frac1x\right) & \text{if } x \ne 0.
\end{cases}
$$
The path $\gamma$ has a bounded derivative everywhere:
$$
\gamma'(x) =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } x = 0, \\
1 + 2ix\sin\left(\frac1x\right) - i\cos\left(\frac1x\right) & \text{if } x \ne 0.
\end{cases}
$$

According to Apostol's definition, $\gamma$ is piecewise smooth, because $\gamma'$ is continuous on $[x_0, x_1)$ and $(x_1, x_2],$ and the one-sided derivatives $\gamma'_-(x_1)$ and $\gamma'_+(x_1)$ both exist. (Both equal $\gamma'(0) = 1.$)

I'm not aware of another book that uses the same definition as Apostol. I'll update this answer if I find any.

According to Ahlfors, *Complex Analysis* (3rd ed. 1979), p.68 (and every other book I've looked at), $\gamma$ is not piecewise smooth, because the one-sided limits $\lim_{x\to x_1-}\gamma'(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to x_1+}\gamma'(x)$ do not exist.