# Find an example for $f$ is differentiable while $f'$ isn't continuous

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Prove or disprove:

There exists a function $f : [−1, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is differentiable
for every $x \in [−1, 1]$, but $f'$ is not continuous on $[−1, 1]$.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [THIS](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292275/discontinuous-derivative).

Comment: @MarkViola:  that question was asking for examples where the derivative is discontinuous at more than one point

Comment: @J.W.Tanner No, it does not ask anything about multiple points of discontinuity.  Why on earth do you infer that?

Comment: @MarkViola:  because the question you linked states as follows: 
"Could someone give an example of a ‘very’ discontinuous derivative? I myself can only come up with examples where the derivative is discontinuous at only one point", but I concede that any answer to that question would surely answer this question

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

Take $$f(x)=x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x^2})$$
for $x\ne 0$ and $f(0)=0$.

$f$ is continuous at $[-1,1]$.

$f$ is differentiable at $[-1,1]$

But

For $x\ne 0$

$$f'(x)=2x\sin(\frac{1}{x^2})-\frac{2}{x}\cos(\frac{1}{x^2})$$

which has no limit at $x=0$.

Comment: when use the squeez theorem to prove the limit at x=0 of f' is 0 .

Comment: @AvivBarel No, the squeeze theorem doesn't work because of the term $\frac 2x$.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah How do you show that $f'(0)$ is well defined?

Comment: @Jam By $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$ which gives $0$.

Answer (score 0):

One such example is $$f(x) = \arcsin x$$

since $$f'(x) = {1\over \sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Comment: This example is not quite correct, since $f$ is not differentiable on the closed interval. I think the question is about finding a discontinuity of $f'$ inside the interval (at least that is more interesting).

Comment: how do i prove arcsin is differentibale