# If $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}f'(x)$ exists, can one infer that $f'(x)$ exists for all $x$ in some interval containing $a$?

Tags: calculus

I just wanted a quick sanity check to make sure I was not misunderstanding something. In Spivak's *Calculus*, there is a theorem in Chapter 11 that reads as follows:

> Suppose that $f$ is continuous at $a$, and that $f'(x)$ exists for all $x$ in some interval containing $a$, except perhaps $x=a$. Suppose, moreover, that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a}f'(x)$ exists. Then $f'(a)$ also exists, and $f'(a)=\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a}f'(x)$

Throughout this text, I have found that Spivak's word-choice is rarely redundant, which brings me to my question:

Why is it mentioned that $f'(x)$ exists for all $x$ in some interval containing $a$ if, later on, we are told that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}f'(x)$ exists?

If I am told that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}f'(x)$ exists, I can infer that $f'(x)$ exists for all $x$ in some interval containing $a$...though perhaps not at $x=a$..., right? (A consequence of the formal FOL defintion of the claim "$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}f'(x)$ exists")

---

I think the following is correct:

TRUE: $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}f'(x)$ exists $\implies$ $f'(x)$ exists for all $x$ in some interval containing $a$ (though, perhaps not for $x=a$)

FALSE: $f'(x)$ exists for all $x$ in some interval containing $a$ (though, perhaps not for $x=a$)$\implies$ $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}f'(x)$ exists

Comment: See, for instance, [ŧħis](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/423279/55235).

Comment: The notation “$\lim_{x\to a}f'(x)$” implies that $f'(x)$ is defined in an open set/interval having $a$ as a limit point. But in my opinion it is better to recall this in plain words.

Comment: Also it should be “$\lim_{x\to a}f'(x)$ exists **and is finite**” but I guess this may be implicitly understood.

Comment: You can think of it as a stylistic choice. Instead of using symbols only, you say (or repeat) things with plain words (for example, $\sum_{i=1}^n i$ vs. "the sum of numbers from 1 to n"). Also, what $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ means depends on the context. In calculus, I believe the most common way is to require that $g$ be defined on some interval of $x=a$ except possibly at $x=a$. In real analysis, however, a more general definition is used where this requirement is relaxed slightly. So, you're right as long as we're talking about calculus and the standard conventions of calculus are assumed.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit subtle, but consider the set $S = \{\frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}_+\} \cup \{0\}$. Define $f : S \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = 0$. Then the notation $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} f(x)$ makes sense when we consider the underlying space to be $S$ and not $\mathbb{R}$, and the limit is 0. This is because the $\delta-\epsilon$ definition becomes

$$\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0 \forall x \in S (|x - 0| < \delta \to |f(x) - 0| < \epsilon)$$

The key is that the quantifier $\forall x$ is relativised to $S$, not to $\mathbb{R}$.

So in principle, we could have some complicated function which is only differentiable one some set like $S \setminus \{0\}$ and where the limit exists.

I don't remember exactly what Spivak's conventions are, but I suspect this is the issue he was trying to avoid.

Comment: Actually Spivak *does* require the function to be defined in a punctured interval around the point! It's not crystal clear from his definition of limit on p. 96, but he mentions it explicitly on p. 104.