# Implications of Darboux's Theorem when: $f$ is differentiable in some interval containing $a$ and $f'$ is discontinuous at $a$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, graphing-functions

I recently derived **Darboux's Theorem**, which states that:

> If $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ and there is a $c$ such that $f'(a) \lt c \lt f'(b)$, then there is an $x \in (a,b)$ such that $f'(x)=c$.

Given this theorem (which also holds for the $f'(a) \gt c \gt f'(b)$ variation), I wanted to explore the implications on what the graph of $f'$ can look like given the following condition:

> Let $f$ be differentiable in some interval containing $a$, where $f'$ is discontinuous at $a \quad (\dagger)$.

---

It seems to me that $(\dagger)$ can only be satisfied by graphs that look something like:

[image: First]

or

[image: Second]

In these above two graphs, one should interpret the zigzag-ing lines approaching $a$ as representing infinite oscillations. Further, the zigzag-ing lines are **NOT** converging to $f'(a)$ (i.e. there is some $\varepsilon \gt 0$ such that in any any neighborhood around $a$, there is an $x$ such that $|f'(x)-f'(a)| \geq \varepsilon$ ).

Importantly, the following graph would be disallowed by Darboux's Theorem:

[image: Third]

The distinction between (graph 1 / graph 2) and (graph 3) is that the first two graphs have the following property:

> For any $\delta \gt 0$ (so long as $a+\delta$ remains confined to a differential interval), for any $y \in [f(a),f(a+\delta)]$, there is an $x \in [a,a+\delta]$ such that $f'(x)=y$. Similarly for $a-\delta$.

(i.e. the first two graphs obey Darboux's Theorem). As you can see, graph 3 has infinitely many neighborhoods where there are $y$ between $f(a)$ and $f(a+\delta)$ that are not mapped into...such that there are no $x \in [a,a+\delta]$ where $f(x)=y$.

Is this the proper understanding?

Comment: Yes, accepting the fact that you want just one point of discontinuity.  In fact, given any set  $D$ that is a meager set of type ${\cal F}_\sigma$ there is a derivative whose set of discontinuities is exactly that set $D$.   So, for example, you can have a dense set of discontinuities and it is hard to say whether they would "look like" your examples.

Comment: I think you will very much enjoy Mark McLure's answer that includes specific examples and nice pictures on this same theme:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292275/discontinuous-derivative

Comment: @B.S.Thomson cheers~