# Cauchy sequences under derivative of a differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, cauchy-sequences

Suppose $f : \Bbb R → \Bbb R$ is differentiable on $\Bbb R$, and let $(x_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence. Is the sequence $(f′(x_n))$ also Cauchy?

My first thought was to take $f(x)=\log x$, and $(x_n)=1/n$. But $\log x$ is not defined for $x=0$. I am unable to think of any other counterexample. Is $(f′(x_n))$ Cauchy?

Comment: Does it matter if you take a sequence of positive numbers?

Comment: Given the completeness of $\mathbb{R}$, this is equivalent to asking if $f'$ is continuous. You can find an example of a discontinuous derivative (about as elementary as it gets) at the top of Mark McClure's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/423279).