# is my proof, that the length of any continuously differentiable curve is finite, rigorous?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, curves

I have a proof but im not sure that it is 100% rigorous.
I started with the defnition of the length of a curve:
Integral from a to b over ||y´(t)|| dt is more or equal then 
|| Integral from a to b y´(t)dt || = ||y(a)-y(b)|| and since y(t) is continuous, then both y(a) and y(b) must be finite numbers, meaning, the length of the curve is finite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not rigorous, because what you are showing is that the length of the curve is at least as large as a finite number. This is not sufficient to prove that the length is not infinite.

Comment: you are right i didnt notice it. Is there another way of showing it?

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable, $f'$ is continuous. You can apply the extreme value theorem to  $f'$.

Comment: @user3257842 Your comment is [not true](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292275/discontinuous-derivative).

Comment: My mistake. $y$ however is stated to be continuously differentiable,  so $y'$ is continuous.