# If f is differentiable on [a,b], is f' continuous on (a,b)?

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Mainly, is this true and why/why not? I am trying to apply the intermediate value theorem to f' but I'm not entirely sure if it's true and I can't find any definitive answers.

Comment: See [Discontinuous derivative.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292275/discontinuous-derivative) for how bad the derivative of a function can be if it is differentiable. The intermediate value property *holds* for $f'$, though.