# How to show $f$ has derivative of ALL order at $z_0$

Tags: complex-analysis

In connection with my question [How to show that $u$ and $v$ have continuous partial derivatives at $(x_0,y_0)?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373544/how-to-show-that-u-and-v-have-continuous-partial-derivatives-at-x-0-y-0) (wrongly stated) I would like to know how to show

$f = u + iv$ is analytic at $z_0\implies$ 1) $f$ has derivative of ALL order at $z_0$; 2) $u, v$ have CONTINUOUS partial derivatives of ALL order at $z_0$.

Comment: Being analytic means having a converging expansion in a power series, therefore it is obvious that such a function has all the derivatives you want. Moreover, if a function is differentiable, it has to be continuous, so obviously every derivative is also continuous.

Comment: @wisefool: Why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: Seemed quite a trivial remark but ... ok

Answer (score 1):

A function $f(z)=u(z)+iv(z)$ is analytic in $0$ (wlog I take $z_0=0$) if we can write
$$u(z)=\sum a_nz^n\qquad v(z)=\sum b_nz^n$$
and both series have positive radius of convergence.
A convergent power series can be differentiated term by term obtaining again a convergent power series, hence the components of an analytic function are differentiable infinitely many times.

Moreover, a differentiable function is continuous, therefore every derivative of an analytic function is continuous.

Comment: wow, a downvote after 6 years... I wonder why