# Can a continuous function have a non-continuous derivative?

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)$ is continuous throughout its domain, can its derivative, g(x) be non-continuous for any point?

If so, what effect does a non-continuous derivative have on the function?

Comment: See [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292275/discontinuous-derivative) and [that thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112067/how-discontinuous-can-a-derivative-be).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, consider the function $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 \qquad x\leq0 \\ x \qquad x>0\end{cases}.$$

It's gradient is defined everywhere except $x=0$

$$f^\prime(x) = \begin{cases}0 \qquad x<0\\1\qquad x>0\end{cases}.$$

If you want a function which is continuous but no-where differentiable [Brownian Motion/Wiener Process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process) satisfies this.

Comment: This function is not differentiable, as it does not have a derivative at 0.

Comment: OP requires $g(x)=f'(x)$ is non-continuous for any point.

Comment: Ahh, so @dsd means $\forall x f^\prime(x)$ is discontinuous?

Comment: @Dan Doesn't the function have a corner point at $x = 0$ and therefore its derivative is not continuos?

Comment: @dsd: the *gradient* is discontinuous but the function itself is continuous as $0$.

Comment: @Dan Oops yeah. But its a corner point, so how can the derivative exist?

Comment: It doesn't that's the point. Is that not what you were after? @Downvoter, could you at least say what is wrong with my answer.

Comment: Dan, I believe the original poster wants $\exists x \, f'(x)$ is discontinuous, but there's no doubt that the phrasing of the question is poor. ("for any point" should be "for some point", and it would help to move the quantifer to the beginning of the sentence.) Also, in the example you gave, $f'(x)$ is continuous at each point of its domain, and hence your $f'(x)$ is a continuous function.

Answer (score 3):

For $x\in [0,1]$, $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}$ for $x\neq 0$.
Then $f(x)$ is differentiable at any point in $[0,1]$, but $f'$ is not continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: ??? $f'$ is not defined in the extremes! Am I wrong?

Comment: I think you are @Maffred . $x\sin \frac{1}{x}$ is not continuous, but if you compute $f'(0)$ by the definition of the derivative, you get that it is $0$ exactly.

Comment: @AmirSagiv Of course I am! This post is 3 years old! xD