# Sufficient condition to show $f$ is monotonically increasing in some neighborhood

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am curious if the following statement holds.

Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function differentiable on the open interval $(a,b)$. Then if $f'(c)>0$ for some $c \in (a,b)$, there exists a neighbourhood of $c$ in which $f$ is monotonically increasing.

An ideal answer to this question would include either a proof or a counterexample.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As noted in other answers the results holds if $f\in C^1$. Consider the following counterexample:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x+2x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x})\quad \text{ if } x\neq 0 \\
0\qquad \quad \qquad \quad \quad \text{ if } x=0
\end{cases}$$

with derivative

$$f^\prime(x)=\begin{cases}
1+4x \sin(\frac{1}{x})-2\cos(\frac{1}{x}) \quad \text{ if } x\neq 0 \\
1\quad \qquad\qquad\qquad\quad \quad\qquad  \text{ if } x=0
\end{cases}$$

Note that $f^\prime(0)>0$ but every neighbourhood of $0$ has negative values (and positive values).

Comment: Why $f$ is differentiable in $0$?

Comment: $x^2 \sin(1/x)$ is a standard example of a function that oscillates around 0, yet is still differentiable (if you define $f(0) = 0$). It's a consequence of the fact that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x \sin(1/x) = 0.$ You can prove this with the squeeze theorem.

Comment: @Maffred. Straight from the definition: $f^\prime(0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} 1+2x\sin(\frac{1}{x})=1$

Comment: Oh well, I was trying to take limit in $f'$ and I couldn't of course! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you know $f'$ is continous, this is trivially true of course.

If it is not, that could be false.

Comment: Can we adapt this http://math.stackexchange.com/a/526286/1284 to create a counterexample?

Comment: I don't understand, since that function is definited in $[0,1]$ thus there is no sense to ask for differentiability in $0$.

Comment: You can define it on [-1,1] and it will be differentiable in (-1,1).

Comment: Yes that is why that example doesn't work, can it be fixed somehow?  Could we extend its domain to $[-1,1]$, make its derivative at $0$ non-zero (add $x$ to it?) and still not have monotonicity in $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$?

Comment: I definitely don't know!!! I hope there is a professor walking around here that can help us, I've never seen an example of a function differentiable that is not $C^1$!

Answer (score 1):

This is true if $f \in C^1((a,b))$, i.e. $f'$ is continuous on $(a,b)$. To see this:

Suppose $f'(c)>0$, where $c \in (a,b)$ and $f \in C^1((a,b))$. Then $\forall$ $\epsilon>0$ $\exists$ $\delta>0$ such that $|x-c|<\delta$ $\Rightarrow$ $|f'(x)-f'(c)|<\epsilon$. Take $\epsilon= \frac{1}{2} f'(c)>0$. Then $\exists$ $\delta>0$ with $|x-c|<\delta$ $\Rightarrow$ $0<\frac{1}{2}f'(c)<f'(x)$, so $f$ is monotone increasing $\forall$ $x \in (a,b)$ with $|x-c|<\delta$.

If $f \notin C^1((a,b))$ I see no reason for the claim to hold.

Comment: I see your point, of course. The thing that's getting me is that, even if the derivative is discontinuous, it still has the intermediate value property per Darboux Theorem. Does that have any significance?

Comment: The intermediate value property says that it will take on every value between two endpoints, but it doesn't say those are the only values.

Comment: Ohh, okay. That's helpful.