# A differentiable function whose derivative is not elementary.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Do we know of any differentiable function whose derivative is not an elementary function? This may be a silly question, but in the light of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599706/why-isnt-there-a-fixed-procedure-to-find-the-integral-of-a-function/599719#599719), as pointed in the comments, finding an example may be pedagogical.

More importantly, can we prove the existence or non-existence of such a function?

**Edit:** An answer that is not in the form $f(x)=\int_0^x g(x)$ would be much appreciated. The point is to find an example that would be of value for the above [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599706/why-isnt-there-a-fixed-procedure-to-find-the-integral-of-a-function/599719#599719).

Comment: What do you mean by "we don't know"?  That seems more like a philosophical question than anything else...

Comment: Well let me add the "soft qustion" tag then.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question!  What do you mean by "we don't know"?

Comment: How about this: for a differentiable function $f$ and point $p$, call $P_{q,\epsilon}$ the decision problem of whether or not $\|f'(p)-q\| < \epsilon.$ Is $P_{q,\epsilon}$ decidable for all $q,\epsilon$?

Comment: My question is well posed and rigorous. I'm looking for a function we can prove to be differentiable, but whose derivative we do not know. Does that answer your question, Mr. @Peterson?

Comment: No.  If you know that it is differentiable, then you know its derivative: it is $f'(x):=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}(f(x+h)-f(x))/h$. Maybe you don't know how to express it in terms of elementary functions; is that what you're getting at?

Comment: I see the trivial answer now, thank you for pointing that out. I will edit accordingly.

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson If $f$ is known at all points and that limit exists, is it obvious that it can be computed?

Comment: I added a comment to your other post as well.  Dave Renfro goes over some general theory in his answer here that is related to this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112067/how-discontinuous-can-a-derivative-be.  The typical derivative in the sense of Baire's theorem is discontinuous on a co-measure zero $F_\sigma$ set, but still satisfies the intermediate value property.  It is difficult to imagine writing down a formula for such a function (I know of no explicit examples), but in the Baire sense they are typical.

Comment: I don't understand the question; but an antiderivative of a non elementary function does have a non elementary derivative, doesn't it?

Comment: Well, if $f(x)$ is elementary i.e. it is composed of algebraic, trigonometric, logarithmic and exponential functions then $f'(x)$ is also elementary because of the rules of derivatives. Hence any example of the kind you are seeking has to be a non-elementary function like say $\Gamma(x)$ or any of elliptic functions like $\text{sn}(x, k)$ for $0 < k < 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x)=\int _0 ^x \text{Erf}.$$