# Neighborhood of a differentiable function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Show that if f is differentiable on a neighborhood of $[a,b]$ and

$f'(a) < m < f'(b)$

then there exists $a$ in $(a,b)$ such that $f'(c) = m.$

First off, what is a neighborhood of an interval? Looking at my books definition of a neighborhood, it defines a neighborhood of a point, like so:

A neighborhood of a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a subset $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that there exists $e>0$ with $B_e(x) \subset X.$

Also, the original statement looks an awful lot like the MVT...

Comment: I imagine it means $f$ is differentiable on an open set containing $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Neighborhood** of a point $p$ is a set $N_r(p)$ consisting of all points such that $d(p,q)<r$. The number $r$ is called the *radius* of $N_r(p)$.
Here $d$ is the distance function.

---

It may look like intermediate value theorem but there are things to be noted.

- For Intermediate value theorem to be true, a function should be continuous in the interval
- A function is differentiable does not mean that the derivative is continuous( Unless specified that the function is continuously differentiable). For a counter-example see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/602571/63095)

---

When the function is continuously differentiable as noted earlier intermediate value theorem would prove the result

But surprisingly, the theorem is true without the continuity constraint of derivative.

For a proof of that part see [Darboux theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29).

Comment: I thought that if a function was differentible on $[a,b]$ then it is automatically true that the function is continuous on $[a,b]$

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable, then $f$ has to be continuous but it is not necessary that $f'$ should be continuous.

Comment: That's a good point. Thank you. Now that i'm thinking about the problem, i think we are given that f is differentiable $[a,b]$ just so that we have it is differentiable on the interval we're working with.. I don't think the fact that it is a neighborhood is significant.


Also, that wikipedia proof uses a lot of things we don't have in class:fermat's theorem, for one. Also first line says "if y equals f'(a) and f'(b)" but by the statement of the problem we can't have that, we have strict inequality.

Comment: @terribleatmath. I think you must be knowing the Fermat's theorem.

Comment: Oh, I do know that, but i've never heard it called that. That's weird that they never gave it a name.

Comment: that still doesn't clear up the wikipedia confusion about "$y equals f'(a) and f'(b)$ though.

Comment: Wikipedia has a slightly different version of the theorem. It says if $f'(x)\le m \le f'(b)$ and the conditions then there is some $c$ in $[a,b]$ such that $f'(c)=m$. And they split it into two cases either $f'(a)$ or $f'(b)$ equals $m$ or $f'(a)<m<f'(b)$. For the first case the proof is obvious and they go on to prove the second case.