# Find a differentiable $f$ such that $f'$ is not continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> Find  a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f':\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is not continuous at any point of $\mathbb{R}$.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you think about a function such as $f(x)=1/x$, which is differentiable everywhere in its domain but $f'$ is not continuous.

Comment: Do you want $f'$ to be discontinuous at some point or at all points of $\Bbb R$? Note that the latter is impossible since $f'$ is Baire one.

Comment: @mathematics2x2life $-x^{-2}$ is continuous.

Comment: See [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/112067/38053).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for a derivative that is discontinuous everywhere on $\Bbb R$. Such a function doesn't exist. Since $f'$ is the pointwise limit of continuous functions, it is a [Baire class $1$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_function) function. A [theorem of Baire](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Baire-Osgood_Theorem) says that the set of discontinuities of $f'$ is a meager subset of $\Bbb R$.