# Differentiable functions whose derivative is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

I am just confused on the structure of  differentiable functions whose derivative is also continuous. How will that continuous function be? What extra restrictions one need to put so as to make a derivative of continuous function continuous? Given an arbitrary continuous function can we be able to say about the continuity of its derivative ? What are the properties of such  functions?

Comment: Given an arbitrary continuous function, it need not be differentiable anywhere, let alone continuously differentiable. see e.g. [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function)

Comment: “Continuous differentiable” means continuous and differentiable, which is redundant, since differentiable implies continuous. What you want to say is continuous**ly** differentiable, i.e., “differentiable in a continuous way”.

Comment: I mean about the functions that have continuous derivative.

Comment: See [cite1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/423279/13130) (specific examples with useful graphs shown), [cite2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/112133/13130) and [cite3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2664789/13130) (how bad things can get), [cite4](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/914128/13130) (how good things must be), [cite5](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2665808/13130) (discussion of ***big*** in the sense of Baire category and in the sense of Lebesgue measure, two notions that arise in describing how bad things can be and how good things must be).