# Oscillation of a Function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f\colon (a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be function. For a non-empty subset $T$ of $(a,b)$, define $\Omega(f,T)=\sup\{|f(x)-f(y)|\colon x,y\in T \}$, and the oscillation function from $(a,b)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ by $x\mapsto \omega_f(x)=\inf\{ \Omega(f,T_x)\}\colon T_x\subseteq (a,b) \mbox{ and } x\in T_x\}$. I couldn't solve few questions about $\omega_f(x)$.

1) Instead of considering all subsets $T_x$ containing $x$, can we consider the sets $B(x,r)\cap (a,b)$, $r>0$, to get the same definition of oscillation function $x\mapsto \omega_f(x)$? In other words, $\inf\{ \Omega(f,T_x)\colon T_x\subseteq (a,b), x\in T_x\} \leq \inf \{\Omega(f,B(x,r)\cap (a,b))\colon r>0 \}$ is clear, but I couldn't prove reverse inequality (if it holds).

2) What can be said about function $x\mapsto \omega_f(x)$? (i.e. is it continuous/ uniformly continuous/ Lipschitz continuous/ differentiable?)

---

Notation: $B(x,r)=(x-r, x+r)$.

Comment: This is a weird definition of oscillation: Take $f(x)$ to be the characteristic function of the rationals (i.e. $f(x)=1$ if $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ and is zero otherwise), $x=0$ and $T=\mathbb{Q}\cap(-1,1)$ then $\Omega(f,T)=0$ and so $\omega_f(0)=0$.

Comment: Oh! You mean, the definition given by considering $B(x,r)$ instead of $T_x$ is better.

Comment: Well, the one with balls behaves more like what you'd expect from the oscillation.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you've defined "oscillation at a point correctly" (I have not tried to proof-read your definitions), the oscillation function is upper semicontinuous. Thus, you can try googling ["oscillation" along with the phrase "upper semicontinuous"](http://www.google.com/search?q=oscillation+%22upper+semicontinuous%22).

The characteristic function of a Cantor set with positive measure shows that the oscillation function can be discontinuous on a set of positive measure.

On the other hand, because the oscillation function is upper semicontinuous (indeed, being a Baire one function suffices), the oscillation function will be continuous on a co-meager set (i.e. at every point in a set whose complement has first Baire category). Because the set of discontinuities of any function is an $F_{\sigma}$ set, the discontinuities of the oscillation function will be an $F_{\sigma}$ set. Putting the last two results together tells us that the oscillation function always has an $F_{\sigma}$ meager (i.e. first Baire category) discontinuity set. I believe this result is sharp in the sense that given any $F_{\sigma}$ meager set $D,$ there exists a function $f:{\mathbb R} \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ such that $D$ is equal to the set of all the points at which the oscillation function ${\omega}_{f}$ is not continuous. I don't have time to look into this now, but I believe this sharp result follows from the more precise results proved in **[1]** and **[2]** (see also **[3]**). Regarding what possibilities exist for sets that are $F_{\sigma}$ and meager, see #1-7 in my answer to the math StackExchange question [How discontinuous can a derivative be?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112067/how-discontinuous-can-a-derivative-be).

**[1]** Zbigniew Grande, [*Quelques remarques sur la semi-continuité supérieure*](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm126/fm12611.pdf), **Fundamenta Mathematicae** 126 #1 (1985), 1-13.

**[2]** Tomasz Natkaniec, *On semicontinuity points*, **Real Analysis Exchange** 9 #1 (1983-1984), 215-232.

**[3]** Janina Ewert, [*On points of lower and upper semicontinuity of multivalued maps*](http://www.thebookshelf.auckland.ac.nz/docs/Maths/PDF2/mathschron020-008.pdf), **Mathematical Chronicle** 20 (1991), 85-88.

*(ADDED NEXT DAY)* My conjecture above (where I said *I believe this result is sharp in the sense that* …) appears to be correct. Indeed, I essentially said as much in this [29 April 2002 sci.math](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sci.math/PdqIT_VuHVM/spvuvlIm6tAJ) post, where I mentioned that a special case of Theorem 5(a) on p. 561 of **[4]** (reference below) implies that for each locally bounded non-negative upper semi-continuous function $f:{\mathbb R} \rightarrow {\mathbb R},$ there exists a function $F:{\mathbb R} \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ such that ${\omega}_{F} = f$. (In analogy with the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, any such function $F$ is called an ${\omega}$-primitive of $f.)$ It is reasonably well known that any $F_{\sigma}$ meager set can be the discontinuity set for an upper semi-continuous function, and the standard proof of this (see the proof sketch below) gives a function that is also locally bounded and non-negative.

> **Proof Sketch:** Let $D$ be an $F_{\sigma}$ meager subset of ${\mathbb R}.$ Express $D$ as the union of a countable (possibly finite) collection $\{P_n\}$ of closed nowhere dense sets and define $f = \sum \left( 2^{-n}\cdot{\chi}_{P_n}\right),$ where ${\chi}_{P_n}$ is the characteristic function of $P_n$ (i.e. ${\chi}_{P_n}(x) = 1$ if $x \in P_{n},$ and ${\chi}_{P_n}(x) = 0$ if $x \notin P_{n}).$ Then $f$ is a bounded non-negative upper semi-continuous function whose discontinuity set is equal to $D.$

Below are some additional references related to this topic. There are other papers not included, and these can be found by looking for papers by these authors and performing a google phrase search for the title of Kostyrko's paper, "Some properties of oscillation".

**[4]** Pavel Kostyrko, [*Some properties of oscillation*](http://dml.cz/dmlcz/130779), **Mathematica Slovaca** 30 #2 (1980), 157-162.

**[5]** Zbigniew Duszyński, Zbigniew Jan Grande, and Stanislaw Petrovich Ponomarev, [*On the* $\omega$-*primitive*](https://eudml.org/doc/32411), **Mathematica Slovaca** 51 #4 (2001), 469-476.

**[6]** Janina Ewert and Stanislaw Petrovich Ponomarev, [*Oscillation and* $\omega$-*primitives*](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rae/1214571360), **Real Analysis Exchange** 26 #2 (2000-2001), 687-702.

**[7]** Cristina Di Bari and Calogero Vetro, [*Primitive rispetto all'oscillazione*](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02871460) [Primitives with respect to oscillation], **Rendiconti del Circolo Matematico di Palermo** (2) 51 #1 (2002), 175-178.

**[8]** Janina Ewert and Stanislaw Petrovich Ponomarev, [*On the existence of* $\omega$-*primitives on arbitrary metric spaces*](https://eudml.org/doc/34568), **Mathematica Slovaca** 53 #1 (2003), 51-57.

**[9]** Stanisław Kowalczyk, [*On the* $\omega$-*problem*](http://www.stolaf.edu/analysis/Budapest2011/V37SSart58pp120-122.pdf), **Real Analysis Exchange** Summer Symposium 2011, 120-122.

Comment: Is there an indication about the connectedness of the set? The example with the fat Cantor set actually demonstrates a totally disconnected set.

Comment: @user48672: The characteristic function of the fat Cantor set is a function from the reals to the reals -- it has the value $1$ at each point in the Cantor set and the value $0$ at each point not in the Cantor set. I believe everything I discussed above is for functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ (although some of the papers I cited consider more general settings, such as ${\mathbb R}^n,$ metric spaces, etc.).

Comment: Incidentally, I realized about a year ago that my "proof sketch" above has a slight flaw --- I think the desired *pairwise disjoint* decomposition at the beginning of the 2nd sentence is not always possible (if it is possible, then an indication of how to carry this out is probably called for). However, I think the proof doesn't need *pairwise disjoint*, but I haven't gotten around to carefully looking into this yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to require that the set $T_x$ in the definition is an ${\it open}$ neighborhood of x, not just an arbitrary set containing x. Then one can take the open sets to be open balls $B(x,r)$ as you wanted, by the definition of the topology on the real line.

Taking $T_x$ to be an open set containing $x$ allows one to relate oscillation to continuity.

Also, one uses the fact that the $T_x$ are open to show that oscillation is upper semi-continuous.