# If $f(x)$ is decreasing, differentiable, and positive for $x\ge1$, must $f'(x)$ be continuous for $x\ge1$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> If $f(x)$ is decreasing, differentiable, and positive for $x\ge1$, must $f'(x)$ be continuous for $x\ge1$?

In general, what conditions on a real-valued differentiable function $f$ guarantee that its derivative is continuous?

Comment: Let $f(x)=4x+x^2\sin(1/x)$, $x\ne0$; $f(0)=0$. $f$ is differentiable and monotone on $(-1,1)$, but $f'$ is not continuous at $x=0$. Appropriate translations/reflections of $f$ should give a counterexample.

Comment: For your second question, you might find [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112067/how-discontinuous-can-a-derivative-be/112133#112133) of interest.

Comment: @DavidMitra Wow - just that one counterexample is food for thought. My obviously suspect intuition wouldn't have had me believing that that derivative could be discontinuous on the interval. Thanks you.