# Is it true that if the derivative of a function is not continuous then the function is not differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

It has been along time since I did real analysis. Someone asked me this question and I could not respond. I am not sure if this is the right place to ask.

He said:

> The function $f: [0, \infty)\mapsto [0, \infty)$ given by $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is not differentiable at $0$ because its derivative $f'(x)=1/(2\sqrt{x})$ is not continuous at $0$.

I said (what I could remember):

> It is not differentiable at $0$ because $\lim_{x\to 0}(f(x)-f(0))/(x-0)=\infty$.

He said that I know that but what I told is it true?

Comment: Hopefully your natural reaction would be that this is not true, since in general one can't show that a function doesn't exist by showing "if it did exist, then it would not be continuous".

Comment: @TonyS.F. Actually, no; they are not saying the same thing.  See my posted answer for a classical example of a function that is everywhere differentiable, but not continuous everywhere.

Comment: A meta/rule-of-thumb argument: if that were true, why on Earth would we have two separate concepts for "differentiable" and "continuously differentiable"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Discontinuous derivative](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/292275/4890).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How discontinuous can a derivative be?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/112067/4890)

Comment: Your friend is wrong: as $f'$ isn't defined for $x=0$ it is neither continuos nor discontinuous, it simply doesn't exist.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The derivative $f'(x)$ of a differentiable function, $f(x)$, need not be continuous itself.  A classical example is the function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2\sin(1/x)&,x\ne0\\\\0&,x=0\end{cases}$$

Then, we have

$$f'(x)=\begin{cases}2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x)&,x\ne0\\\\0&,x=0\end{cases}$$

Clearly, $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)$ does not even exist while $f'(0)=0$ as shown by

$$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h^2\sin(1/h)-0}{h}=0$$

> **Hence, we have an example of a function that is differentiable at $x=0$ although it derivative is discontinuous at $x=0$.**

Answer (score 9):

Another counterexample, which has the additional property $\limsup\limits_{x\to 0^+} f'(x)=\infty$ and $\liminf\limits_{x\to 0^+} f'(x)=-\infty$ is $$f(x):=x^2\left( \sin\frac1x\right)\ln\lvert x\rvert$$
whose derivative (basically the same reason as DR.MV's answer) is $$f'(x)=\begin{cases}2x\left( \sin\frac1x\right)\ln\lvert x\rvert-\color{blue}{\left(\cos\frac1x\right)\ln\lvert x\rvert}+x\sin\frac1x&\text{if }x\ne0\\ 0&\text{if }x=0\end{cases}$$

However, *there are restrictions* on how a derivative can be discontinuous at a given point. For instance, an interesting question for the sake of your problem is:

> Let $f$ be a differentiable function $[0,\varepsilon)\to \Bbb R$. Can $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+} f'(x)=\infty$ hold?

The answer is **no**: in fact, assume as a contradiction that this were the case. Then, by extending $f$ to $$\overline f(x):=\begin{cases} f(x)&\text{if }x\in[0,\varepsilon)\\ f'(0)x+f(0)&\text{if }x<0\end{cases}$$

we can assume that $f$ is a differentiable function on $(-\infty,\varepsilon)\ni 0$ with *constant derivative for $x\le0$*.

Now, due to Darboux's theorem, the image under $f'$ of any interval $(-\delta,\delta)$ must be an interval $I$ containing $f'(0)$. But this cannot be the case, because, since $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}f'(x)=\infty$, $\{f'(0)\}\subsetneqq f'(-\delta,\delta)\subseteqq \{f'(0)\}\cup [f'(0)+1,\infty)$ for $\delta$ sufficiently small. Absurd.

With the same idea, you can also prove that the derivative of a function, though it can be discontinuous, it cannot have jump discontinuities.

**Added:** To spill the beans, at each point $x$ it must hold $$\liminf_{t\to x^+} f'(t)\le f'(x) \le \limsup_{t\to x^+}f'(t)\\ \liminf_{t\to x^-} f'(t)\le f'(x) \le \limsup_{t\to x^-}f'(t)$$

Comment: For reference: [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) states that if $f$ is a real-valued, differentiable function, then $f'$ has the intermediate value property.

Comment: I was going to point out both of your points. An example of a differentiable function with unbounded derivative that seems simpler to me is given by $x^2\sin(1/x^2)$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich In fact, while I was juggling with logarithms, I started wondering if I was overcomplicating. How could I not think of it? :D

Comment: What does the subset symbol with the equal/different sign below it mean? "$\subsetneqq$"

Comment: @someonewithpc "$A\subsetneqq B$" (or "$A\subsetneq B$") means "$A\subseteq B$ but $A\neq B$".

Comment: @someonewithpc "$\subseteqq$", "$\subseteq$" and "$\subset$" are all symbols for subset, though some authors use $A\subset B$ when they additionally require $A\ne B$ (my high school maths book had the fetish of using "$A\subset B$" to indicate a *proper* and *non-empty* subset of $B$). As far as I know, "$A\subseteqq B$"  and "$A\subseteq B$" are sheer synonimous which always indicate the fact that all the elements of $A$ are elements of $B$. I like being unambiguous.

Comment: In your discussion following the proposition in the shaded box, you define an extension, $\bar f$ of $f$ for $x<0$. Yet, $\bar f$ never appears thereafter.  And I'm not sure of its relevance.  Since $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f'(x)=\infty$, then for all $B>0$, there exists an $x_0$ such that $f'(x)>B$ whenever $0<x<x_0$.  And since $f$ is differentiable at $0$, and $f'$ satisfies the intermediate value property on $[0,x_0]$, then there exists a number $0<\xi<x_0$ such that $f'(0)<f'(\xi)<f'(x_0)$.  This is the desired contradiction and $\bar f$ was never implicated.  Does this make sense?  ;-))

Comment: @Dr.MV In the sentence after the definition I said "We can assume that $f$ is a differentiable function $(-\infty,\varepsilon)\to \Bbb R$ such with constant derivative for $x<0$" (it should have been $x\le 0$, now that I think about it, and I'll edit it).The reason for that assumption is replacing $f$ with $\overline f$. To be fair, at the time I did not bother checking if Darboux was valid "at the boundary" (and wikipedia does not mention it), so I opted to reduce explicitly to the case where $f$ was differentiable on a whole neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: Well, I like your answer.  So, +1

Comment: @Dr.MV In my proof "$f'(x)=f'(0)$ for $x\le0$" comes into play because, since I technically deal with the limit only on the right and consider a two-sided interval containing $0$ to apply Darboux, I want the function not to take intermediate values *on the left*: that would spoil the contradiction.

Comment: So, why not ignore the left?

Comment: @Dr.MV Uhm... yeah, I guess I was overcomplicating things. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a thought to what others already said.

As Dr MV pointed out, a function is differentiable at a point if the limit of the difference quotient exists and is finite. That's it. Continuity of the derivative is something more. Therefore your answer was correct.

However, continuity is required when we say that a function $f$ is in $\mathcal{C}^1(I)$ (here $I$ is an interval): $f$ is in $\mathcal{C}^1(I)$ if it is differentiable in $I$, and the derivative is also continuous in $I$.

In this context, the example given by Dr MV is an example of a function which is differentiable everywhere, but does not belong to $\mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R})$.