# Example of a function that is differentiable but it's derivative is not differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Can someone give me an example of a function $g:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ that is differentiable but the derivative $g'$ is not differentiable and prove there assertion.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/112067/413023)

Comment: @DHMO Duplicate? Really?

Comment: @zhw. If it isn't continuous how can it be differentiable?

Comment: Come now @Gibberish, surely you  have some ideas on this.

Comment: There exists a continuous $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ that is nowhere differentiable.  Let $g(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$.

Comment: is the weierstrass function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $g(x)=x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x} ) $ when $x\neq 0$ and $g(0)=0$ .

then $g'$ exists at all point and is given by $f'(x)=2x \sin(\frac{1}{x})-\cos(\frac{1}{x}) ,g'(0)=0 $

But $g'$ is not continuous at $x=0$ as $\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ is not continuous at $0$ . As $g'$ is not continuous ,it is not differentiable .

Answer (score 1):

here is an example: $f(x) = \int_0^x |t| dt.$  by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $f$ is differentiable and its derivative is $|x|$ but $|x|$ is not differentiable at $x = 0.$