# Can differentiation be thought of as a function?

Tags: functions, derivatives

Would it be wrong to think of differentiation as a function whose domain is the set of differentiable functions and co-domain is the set of all functions whose domain and range are some subsets of real numbers?

Comment: Differentiation is an operator - it transforms a differentiable function into another function.

Comment: See http://www.codecogs.com/library/maths/calculus/differential/the-d-operator.php.

Comment: Differentiation can be viewed as a function in the sense you describe. Note carefully, however, that the image of the differentiation operator is (tautologically) the set of all _derivatives_, a complicated space; see for example [How discontinuous can a derivative be?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112067)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang well, it's not necessary to know the exact _image_ of the operator. As long as you know a co-domain, you can use the operator. Knowing the image is important when you want to consider _inverting_ the operator, but there it would make sense to just take the integrable functions.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: That's why I left a comment, not an answer. ;) The important (and possibly surprising, and probably of interest to the OP) point is, the image of differentiation is not a simple, familiar function space. (Incidentally, the space of integrable functions is _not_ a suitable domain for an inverse: Many integrable functions do not satisfy the intermediate value property and so [are not derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux's_theorem_%28analysis%29). Separately but maybe also relevant, many derivatives are unbounded, and consequently not integrable.)

Answer (score 29):

Yes, differentiation can be thought of as a function from the set of differentiable functions to the set of functions which are derivatives of a differentiable function. (which is, as Dr. MV points out in a comment, not quite the set of integrable functions).

Such things, which map functions to functions, are typically called [operators](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Operator.html), but this is just a convention, you can think of them as functions just fine.

Answer (score 19):

Differentiation of a function is a linear operator, a function on a set of functions.

Differentiation *at a point* is a linear functional, a function which maps elements of a vector space to it's underlying field, in this case functions to real numbers.

Comment: This is a solid answer! (+1)

Comment: Solid answer except that I feel like if you tell some people that something is a "function" when it's really a functional, they would get annoyed. :\ +1 nonetheless...

Comment: @Mehrdad: A functional is a function.I would hope that anyone annoyed by that would think hard about what exactly is bothering them so much.

Answer (score 2):

Look up differential forms. I think you'll find that what you're describing closely resembles them. In fact, any course on differential topology or differential geometry should present this perspective.

Answer (score 2):

Differentiation can indeed be  thought of as a function, but it was not viewed that way by the creators of the calculus.  The first mathematician to think of differentiation as an operator from functions to functions was Euler's successor [Lagrange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph-Louis_Lagrange).