# Derivative and Antiderivative: Suppose $F: [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose $F: [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$.
Does it follow that $\int_{a}^{b} F' = F(b)-F(a)$?

This is an interesting question. Don't we have to assume that $F'(x)$ is always equal to $f(x)$ for this to work? In other words, does $F(x)$ being differentiable always guarantee that $F'(x)$ is integrable?

Thanks!

Comment: It's possible for $F'$ to be unbounded, hence not Riemann integrable, e.g., $F(x) = x^{2} \sin(1/x^{2})$ for $x \neq 0$, $F(0) = 0$. More interestingly, it's possible for $F'$ to exist everywhere, but to be discontinuous on a set of positive Lebesgue measure, see [How discontinuous can a derivative be?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112067).

Comment: To expand on Andrew's answer, $F'$ may even be bounded and not Riemann integrable. [Volterra's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function) is a standard example.

Comment: Note, however, that this deficiency only exists with the Riemann integral. If $F:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and $F'$ is bounded, then $F'$ is both Lebesgue integrable and Henstock–Kurzweil integrable.

Comment: You ask whether one must assume something is equal to $f(x)$ but you have not defined anything called $f(x). \qquad$

Comment: It bothers me that you left out the $dx$

Comment: @Math_QED That's fairly common notation beyond first year calculus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several questions in the post that are intertwined, and I'll try to list a bunch of definitions/conclusions below in the hope to answer your question (all integrations below are Lebesgue integration):

Firstly, if $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$, then the derivative of $F$ is $f$ a.e.

> Suppose $f:\mathbb R \mapsto \mathbb R$ is integrable and $a \in \mathbb R$. Define $F(x) = \int_a^xf(y)\,dy$ as the antiderivative of $f$. Then $F$ is differentiable almost everywhere and $F'(x)=f(x)$ a.e.

---

Secondly however, if $f$ is the derivative of $F$ a.e., $F$ is not necessarily the antiderivative of $f$. One good-enough relationship is based on functions of bounded variation. (But notice that we need more condition in order to guarantee the equality)

> Functions of bounded variation are differentiable and can be written as the difference of two increasing functions. If $F$ is increasing, then $F'$ exists a.e., and $\int_a^bF'(x)\,dx \le F(b) - F(a)$;

Notice that here the equality is not guaranteed.

**Example**: let $F$ be the Cantor-Lebesgue function, then it is differentiable with $F'(x)= 0$ a.e., and thus 
$$1=F(1)-F(0) \color{red}> 0 = \int_0^1F'(x) \, dx $$

---

Finally, here is one stricter condition under which the equality is achieved.

> If $F$ is absolutely continuous, then $F'$ exists a.e. and $\int_a^bF'(x)\,dx = F(b) - F(a)$.

One could consider absolutely continuous as a special case of bounded variation, because it could be proved that if $f$ is absolutely continuous, then it is of bounded variation.