# Does the definite integral of a function's derivative exists?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ and let $|f'(x)|\le 2$ for all real $x$.

Is the derivative integrable? I know that the derivative needn't be integrable, but if it's bounded can it be so? What is the condition for a derivative to be integrable? (I mean Riemann-Integrable)

Comment: It's evidently Lebesgue integrable, since it's measureable and bounded. Indicate what you mean by integrability.

Comment: thanks for pointing out; Riemann Integrable.

Comment: Whether it's a derivative or not, a bounded function $g \colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable if and only if the set of its discontinuities is a (Lebesgue) null set.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112067/how-discontinuous-can-a-derivative-be) for some information about how badly behaved a derivative can be.