# Can the maximum value of a sequence be found by differentiation.

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

Can we find the maximum value of a sequence by considering a differentiable function which has the same values as the sequence on integers. Is it true that if the maximum occurs at some value $a_m$ for some integer $m$, then the differentiable function would be would have an extremum in the interval $[m-1,m+1]$?

> Formally, let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be an everywhere diffrentiable function, then if $\exists\ n \in  \mathbb{Z} $  such that  $  f(n)> g(m)\ \forall \ m \in \mathbb{Z}-\left\{n\right\}$, then $\exists\ c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(c)=0$ and $|c-n| \le1$

I tried to create a counter example by plotting different curves on the plane but I couldn't find one nor could I prove it. Is the above statement true/false?

Comment: It's certainly true if the derivative is continuous.

Comment: Can you point me to a source where it is proven and what if the derivative isn't continuous?

Comment: $f(n)>f(n-1)$ implies there is a point of positive derivative between $n-1$ and $n$.  $f(n)>f(n+1)$ implies there is a point of negative derivative between $n$ and $n+1$.

Comment: @lulu what if the derivative is not continuous?

Comment: @Peter  I was thinking only of the continuous case.

Comment: @Peter An everywhere differentiable function always has continuous derivative. If you relax the "everywhere differentiable" requirement on $f$, then the statement is clearly false, because $f$ might not be differentiable at the critical value.

Comment: @Reese, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292275/discontinuous-derivative for discussions of everywhere differentiable functions with discontinuous derivatives. Also worth a look: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112067/how-discontinuous-can-a-derivative-be

Comment: @GerryMyerson I stand corrected!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $n\in\Bbb Z$ and $f(n)>f(m)$ for every $m\in\Bbb Z\setminus\{n\}$.

Now consider the restriction
$$g(x)=f(x)\text{ for }x\in[n-1,n+1]$$

Then $g$ has a maximum (Weierstrass' theorem) and it is not $g(n-1)$ or $g(n+1)$, since $g(n)$ is greater than both. At this maximum, the derivative of $g$ and $f$ is zero.

*Remark*: this proves something slightly stronger. You can say (with your notation) that $|c-n|<1$.