# Is there functions $f$ derivable on $]a,b[$ s.t. $f'$ is almost nowhere continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Is there functions $f:[a,b]\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ derivable on $]a,b[$ s.t. $f'$ is almost nowhere continuous ? Or at least not continuous on a set of measure strictly positive.

Comment: See [How discontinuous can a derivative be?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112067/how-discontinuous-can-a-derivative-be)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have [Volterrra's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function), made by gluing together lots of copies of $x^2\sin(1/x)$. It has derivative which is discontinuous on a [fat Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set), with  positive measure.