# If a function is differentiable in [a,b] then its derivative is continious almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis

Is it true that for every differentiable function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ its derivative $f'$ is continious in  $[a,b]$ and  it can be discontinious in isolated points? If not, then can you find a counterexample?

PS: If there is a problem in the translation let me now.

Comment: This looks related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112067/how-discontinuous-can-a-derivative-be. From the answer: *"D (the discontinuity set) can have positive measure."*

Comment: Not every function even has a derivative; do you mean for every differentiable function?

Comment: Yes sorry I mean differentiable.

Comment: Your title makes sense, but your first sentence below it makes no sense.

Comment: If it's Lipschitz, you can use Radamacher's theorem to get that the function is differentiable a.e.