# Can we find an interval $(x_0-δ,x_0+δ)$ so $f'$ is continuous when $f'(x_0)$ is a discontinuity point?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function.
Suppose that  $f'(x_0)$ is a discontinuity point then can we always find an interval $A=(x_0-δ,x_0)$ so $f'$ is continuous in $A$ ?To make it more clear. $f'$ must have a certain behavior as $x$ approaches $x_0$ in order for $f'(x_0)$ to be a discontinuity point .I am looking for that behavior .

Comment: Are you really asking if a function discontinuous at $x_0$ can be continuous in a neghbourhood of $x_0$?

Comment: The question is about the  derivative of a differentiable function not every function

Comment: @DR.X This doesn't matter; the locality of continuity is a property that holds for every function, including those that are derivatives of another function..

Comment: What do you mean with "$f'(x_0)$ is a discontinuity point"?

Comment: a point where the limit does not exist

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How discontinuous can a derivative be?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112067/how-discontinuous-can-a-derivative-be)

Comment: I think he's asking if the discontinuities of the derivative must be isolated.

Comment: The question makes no sense at all. Since you would like some help here, you need to help MSE by asking a clear and precise question.

Answer (score 2):

No, because continuity is a local property. If $f$ is discontinuous at $x$, then $f|_A$ is discontinuous for every open set $A$ containing $x$.

Comment: Maybe I did not expess it correctly . What I am saying is that as $x\rightarrow x_0(+)$ then the image of $f'(x)$ would move in the y axis in a continuous way and not ''jump'' from one value to the other.

Comment: @DR.X Do you mean: If $f'$ is discontinuous at $x_0$, then is there a $\delta$ such that $f'|_{(x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta) - \{x_0\}}$ is continuous? That is, is there a small enough neighbourhood of $x_0$ such that $f'$ is still continuous in that smaller area around $x_0$? If so, then the answer is still no, the discontinuity set of a derivative can be dense.

Comment: I know that it can be dense, but how can it get from one discontinuity to the other without a no matter small interval. What kind of discontinuities can the derivative have ? We know that it cannot have ''jump'' discontinuities because it satisfies the Intermediate value theorem , a kind of discontinuity that it can have is that of the derivate of $f(x)=x^2 sin(1/x) $ $ f(0)=0$. Are there any more?

Comment: To make it more clear. $f'$ must have a certain behavior as $x$ approaches $x_0$ in order for $f'(x_0)$ to be a discontinuity point .I am looking for that behavior .

Comment: @DR.X Discontinuous functions can have a lot of behaviors and properties, you're going to need to be more specific.To start with, I vaguely remember there being a classification of the types of discontinuities that a function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ may have in chapter $4$ of Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis. Perhaps look there?

Comment: Thank you for the information, I will . I can  specify that am talking about the discontinuity of $f'$ .