# There is no differentiable function $f:(0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ whose derivative is continuous on $(0,1)\cap \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

> **Theorem:** There is no differentiable function $f:(0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ whose derivative is continuous EXACTLY on $E=(0,1)\cap \mathbb{Q}$.

**Proof:** Since $E$ is a meagre set, it is not $G_\delta$, thus there cannot exist a set $D(f)$ of continuity of $f$ such that $D(f)\subset E$, since $D(f)$ must be a $G_\delta$ dense set in $E$.

Please let me know if my idea is correct. I think that I may not yet have grasped the related concepts very well.

Comment: Is this some non-standard definition of continuity? The usual epsilon-delta one works fine for intervals in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: what do you call continuity on a disconnected set ? because $f=1$ and $f'=0$ seem pretty continuous to me.

Comment: I suspect the OP means "whose derivative is continuous *exactly* on $E$", i.e. for which $E$ is the set of points at which $f'$ is continuous.

Comment: Please restate the problem. There are things you have misstated.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/112133/44121

Comment: I apologze. @AlexKruckman is right. Edited.