# A counterexample of a differentiable function on an interval whose derivative is discontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $f(x)$ be a real-valued differentiable function on an interval $I$ of $\mathbb R$, then is $f'(x)$ necessary to be continuous?
I don't think so and I'm trying to construct a counterexample. $\sin\frac{1}{x}$ may be the key element but $x\sin\frac{1}{x}$ failed me.

Comment: More than you asked for, but perhaps of interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112067/how-discontinuous-can-a-derivative-be

Comment: @HansLundmark Thanks, I'll check it out later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^{2}\sin(1/x)$ for $x\ne 0$, $f(0)=0$, then $f'(0)=0$, $f'(x)=2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x^{2})$, for $x\ne 0$. You may try to investigate $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f'(x)$ to see what is going on.

Comment: Aha! I was soooo closed.