# When is the derivative of a function continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

I know that there exists functions where the derivatives are discontinuous, but most of the examples look sort of artificial. For example: the function $ f(x)  = x^2  \sin (1/x)$ when x is non zero and taking value zero when x is zero. Here the original function itself has an undefined point. So I am a bit  confused as to whether seemingly ordinary functions can have discontinuous derivatives.

Hence I am looking for any sort of lemmas or theorems which will give hints to as when a function will have a  continuous derivative.

Comment: Written as $f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2\sin(1/x)&x\ne 0\\0&x=0\end{cases}$, the original function does not have undefined points ...

Comment: This maybe relative-Looks like it is a dominant example: :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292275/discontinuous-derivative

Comment: Sum, differences, products, quotients (where defined), compositions of functions with continuous derivatives are again functions with continuous derivatives.

Comment: Note also that if $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $f’$ has a limit at $b$, then $f$ is differentiable at $b$ and $f’$ is continuous at $b$.

Comment: @Mindlack sorry can you explain it non rigorously?

Comment: If the (directional) derivative does not exist at a point, it has no limit at this point. Say that $f(x)$ is smooth on $x > 0$ but not differentiable at $0$: then $f’(x)$ has no likit when $x \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Discontinuous derivative.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292275/discontinuous-derivative)

Comment: I picked the dupe target on the basis of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/423279/468350), which I think addresses this question.  [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/112133/468350) to [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/112133/468350) may also be relevant.

Comment: A derivative always satisfies the intermediate value theorem, whether it is continuous or not. So if it's discontinuous it can't have a simple jump discontinuity, it has to fail to have a limit entirely.

Comment: @MattSamuel thankyou for that comment. I was looking for such theorems.