# Prove/disprove, Newton Leibniz theorem and the fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration

Let $ f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R} $ be an integrable function with a primitive function.

Define:

$ F\left(x\right)=\intop_{a}^{x}f\left(t\right)dt. $

Prove/disprove:

$F$ is differentiable and it follows that $ F'=f $

So, I'm pretty sure that this is false. Otherwise we probably wouldn't mention continious function in the fundamental theorem of calculus.

But I'm having trouble finding a counter example. Obviously we do not want a continuous function as a counter example, so we are looking for a non continuous function, but the discontinuities of the function should be essential discontinuity, because otherwise it wouldn't follow Darbo's theorem and $ f $ wouldn't has an antiderviative.

Also, we still want $ f $ to be bounded, because otherwise it wouldn't be integrable.

So I guess it should be some trigonometric function that "explodes" around its discontinuities points.

I'd like some help finding one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly should "primitive function" indicate here? Usually it would mean that there is a function $g$ such that $g'(t) = f(t)$ holds for all $t$.

Comment: Im not familier with thia function, but from a quick google: isnt it continious?

Comment: @Danirl Ficher Indeed that's what I ment when I wrote "primitive function". Though, if $ f $ is not continious I think it does not necesseraly correct that F is also an antideriviative of $  f(t) $

Comment: In that case, Theorem 7.21 of Rudin's *Real And Complex Analysis* shows that $F'(t) = f(t)$ for all $t$. This deals with the Lebesgue integral, but I think assuming that $f$ is Riemann integrable allows only very small simplifications in the proof.

Comment: Im sorry Im not familier at all with Lebesgue integral (its not in our course syllabus, we'll learn it in the next calculus course). Do you claim that this is actually correct?

Comment: Yes. If $g \colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at every point of $[a,b]$, and $f(t) = g'(t)$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, then $$g(x) - g(a) = \int_a^x f(t)\,dt$$ holds for all $x \in [a,b]$. Thus $F$ differs from $g$ by a constant, showing that $F$ is differentiable and $F'(t) = g'(t) = f(t)$ on $[a,b]$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I guess you used here Newton leibniz theorem. I know that if $ g $ is an antideriviative of $ f $ then $ \intop_{a}^{b}f\left(t\right)dt=g\left(b\right)-g\left(a\right) $. But is it still hold's when $ x $ is'nt constant and $ f $ does not necessary continious?

Comment: I don't know which version of the FTC is called Newton Leibniz theorem. (I don't really see either of the two considering pathological functions.) What I'm saying is that it is sufficient that a) $f$ is a derivative (has a primitive) and b) $f$ is integrable to deduce that the indefinite integral of $f$ is a primitive of $f$. We don't need continuity for that. But the proof is much harder than the continuous case, which explains that the FTC as stated in earlier courses refers to continuous $f$.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3684600/72031).